# Yii2 - How We can Change the element that Will be update via Pjax response

Tags: yii2, pjax

How can i change the element(tag) that will be update via Server response .

this is my form

```
<div  id="test" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">ورود به سایت</div>
                <?php
                \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['enablePushState'=>FALSE]);
                $loginModel=new \common\models\LoginForm();
                $form=\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id'=>'form-login',                        
                    'options'=>['data-pjax'=>''],
                    'method'=>'post',
                    'action'=>['site/login'],

                ]);

                echo $form->field($loginModel, 'username')->textInput()->label('نام کاربری');
                echo $form->field($loginModel, 'password')->passwordInput()->label('رمز عبور');
                echo $form->field($loginModel,'captchaLogin')->widget(yii\captcha\Captcha::className(),[
                    'attribute'=>'captchaLogin',
                    'captchaAction'=>'site/captchaLogin',
                    'id'=>'captchaLogin',                                            
                ])->label('کد امنیتی');                                        
                ?>
                <div style="color:#999;margin:1em 0">             
                     برای یادآوری رمز عبور <?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('اینجا کلیک کنید', ['site/request-password-reset']) ?>.
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::submitButton('ورود', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login','value'=>'ورود']) ?>
                </div>
                <div id="my"></div>

                <?php 
                \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end(); 
                \yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
                ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

basically all of `<div id=#test></div>` content updates by new contents . i want push all responses into `<div id="my"></div>` tag and no update anothers.

Comment: add an id of your pjax container....

Comment: added , still not working ...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the **pjax:beforeReplace** method and push all the contents in `<div id="my"></div>` instead of `<div id=#test></div>`.

Here is the [documentation link](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

For Ex.

`$(function(){
    $('#test').on('pjax:beforeReplace',function(contents, options){
       $('#my').html(contents);
    });
});`

Your js code may look like this.